# php + sql server login & sessions

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

Hello i am trying to create a login and session script with php to use for sql server and i cannot get it to work, it seams like no mater what i put into the login form aslong as it validates it will work, i cannot figure out what is wrong with the code however, i've just resently started using php and sql server and have not gotten the knowlage to figure out the problem for my self if soeone could help that would be great, also if you knwo any good tutorial sites that use sql server and php could you please share as there doesnt seam to be that many good tutorial sites for them sadly. any help is much welcomed at this stage. my main problem is, is that it isnt checking if the information posted in the html form exists in the database. (i have taken out the js validation as it doesnt seam nessessary however that works)

Login.html

```
<form name="log" action="log_action.php" method="post">
Username: <input class="form" type="text" name="uNm"><br />
Password: <input class="form" type="password" name="uPw"><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

log_action.php

```
session_start();
$serverName = "(local)";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"mydatabase","UID"=>"myusername", "PWD"=>"mypassword");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false){
    echo "Error in connection.\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$username = $_REQUEST['uNm'];
$password  = $_REQUEST['uPw'];
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM li WHERE uNm='$username' AND uPw='$password'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
if($stmt == true){
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['uNm'] = $username;
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}else{
    header('Location: error.html');
    die();
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['valid_user']!=true){
    header('Location: error.html');
    die();
}
?>
```

Thank you for any help you guys might be able to bring

Comment: As an aside, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), it is extremely dangerous to directly concatenate user input into a query.  Learn about parametrized queries to defend against this.

Comment: Also, it isn't entirely clear what your question is.  First you say "i cannot get it to work", then you say, "no mater what i put into the login form aslong as it validates it will work".  What, exactly, is the problem you are running into?

Comment: it's not checking if the username and password exists in the database, regardless of what i put in, it will take me to the login page, where if it doesn't exist it should take me to an error page. and yes i plan to do sql injection prevention once i get a few scripts up nd running and am comfortable enough workinb with sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you never actually check the results of the query.

```
if($stmt == true){
```

only checks that the query executed without errors - it says nothing about the results returned by the query.

Therefore, you need to use the [sqlsrv_fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch.php) function (or one of the related functions) to actually examine the result of the query.

In your particular case, simply checking if the result set has rows with [sqlsrv_has_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-has-rows.php) should be sufficient.

Comment: okay i had a look at the has rows link, and using it ive adjusted my script and it says it has rows, so thats good it also only works when im using the right username and password so now just to get the session to work, thanks allot!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if it ins't how you'd answer, I am just a newbie here, but I think I have something to contribute. See if this code works for you:

```html
<?php

#starts a new session
session_start();

#includes a database connection
include 'connection.php';

#catches user/password submitted by html form
$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

#checks if the html form is filled
if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    echo "Fill all the fields!";
}else{

#searches for user and password in the database
$query = "SELECT * FROM [DATABASE_NAME].[dbo].[users] WHERE user='{$user}' AND"
         ."password='{$password}' AND active='1'";
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);  //$conn is your connection in 'connection.php'

#checks if the search was made
if($result === false){
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

#checks if the search brought some row and if it is one only row
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) != 1){
       echo "User/password not found";
}else{

#creates sessions
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)){
       $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
       $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
       $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user'];
       $_SESSION['level'] = $row['level'];
    }
#redirects user
    header("Location: restrict.php");
}
}

?>
```

If you want, you can do the same with sqlsrv_fetch combined with sqlsrv_get_field().
Sth like:

```html
<?php
session_start();

[... CONNECTION ...]

[...  your POST request ...]

[... check your forms ...]

 Here is the past that is kinda particular
 [... YOUR QUERY ...]

$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query);

if(!sqlsrv_fetch($result)){
  die(print_r(sqlsrv_erros()),true);
}else{
  $_SESSION['id'] = sqlsrv_get_field($result, 0);
  [... and so on ...]
}
?>
The sqlsrv_fetch() only holds a row and sqlsrv_get_field reads the content of that row. One grabs the other punches. Once you only is retrieving data from the database if the row that contains user AND password exists, sqlsrv_fetch() will only stay with the row that does have the parameters passed by form, if they exist in the database.
```

I don't recommend, but you can use sqlsrv_num_rows() to check the number of rows, but you need to set some parameters to the sqlsrv_query: $sqlsrv_query($conn, $stmt, array($params), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET )) or sth like that.

Thank you for the opportunity!!! :D

Good luck!